# connecting to spring ldap server outside of corporate network

Tags: spring-boot

We have an ldap server which is outside the corporate network, and our application is trying to connect to this ldap server which is behind proxy server.So how this can be done using Spring ldap

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ensure your question is elaborate enough, stating what is the issue (clearly), give any config details and what you have tried. These will help to resolve the issue.

Comment: SpringBoot will not help in this. You have to get in touch with Security/Administration team to address this issue. I am assuming your org is also using the same LDAP for other application, get understanding from those applications team as well.